# Add all values in column to another data frame one by one

Tags: r, list

Apologize for the obscure title...

I have a column `Dato` in data frame `tucker_df` and another data frame `jrn_not`. I am trying to add each row in `tucker_df$Dato` to each row in the data frame `jrn_not` in new column `jrn_not$date`. The final date frame will have 147x12 rows where each `Name` appear in five separate rows with five different dates in a new column `date`

```
tucker_df$Dato
  [1] "2022-02-11" "2022-02-02" "2022-02-02" "2022-01-31" "2022-01-28" "2022-01-27" "2022-01-21" "2022-01-17" "2022-01-15" "2022-01-04" "2021-12-21"
 [12] "2021-12-02" "2021-11-30" "2021-11-11" "2021-10-30" "2021-10-20" "2021-10-15" "2021-10-05" "2021-09-24" "2021-09-22" "2021-09-18" "2021-09-04"
 [23] "2021-09-03" "2021-09-02" "2021-08-28" "2021-08-20" "2021-08-18" "2021-08-12" "2021-08-10" "2021-08-03" "2021-08-03" "2021-07-28" "2021-07-22"
 [34] "2021-07-15" "2021-07-13" "2021-07-13" "2021-07-08" "2021-07-06" "2021-07-01" "2021-06-18" "2021-06-16" "2021-06-15" "2021-06-09" "2021-06-02"
 [45] "2021-05-15" "2021-05-12" "2021-05-06" "2021-04-19" "2021-04-16" "2021-04-13" "2021-04-03" "2021-03-31" "2021-03-24" "2021-03-18" "2021-03-16"
 [56] "2021-03-12" "2021-03-11" "2021-02-22" "2021-02-16" "2021-02-11" "2021-01-08" "2020-12-10" "2020-08-04" "2020-07-07" "2020-06-30" "2020-06-12"
 [67] "2020-06-11" "2020-06-09" "2020-06-05" "2020-06-04" "2020-06-03" "2020-05-29" "2020-05-28" "2020-05-27" "2020-05-22" "2020-05-20" "2020-05-05"
 [78] "2020-04-29" "2020-04-28" "2020-04-18" "2020-04-16" "2020-04-07" "2020-04-07" "2020-03-26" "2020-03-12" "2020-03-05" "2020-02-22" "2020-02-21"
 [89] "2020-02-14" "2020-02-12" "2020-02-11" "2020-02-05" "2020-02-04" "2020-01-24" "2020-01-23" "2020-01-17" "2020-01-16" "2020-01-16" "2020-01-15"
[100] "2020-01-09" "2019-12-20" "2019-12-18" "2019-12-12" "2019-12-04" "2019-11-26" "2019-11-21" "2019-11-15" "2019-10-29" "2019-10-16" "2019-10-08"
[111] "2019-09-27" "2019-09-24" "2019-09-20" "2019-09-19" "2019-09-12" "2019-09-06" "2019-08-01" "2019-07-30" "2019-07-03" "2019-06-26" "2019-06-12"
[122] "2019-06-04" "2019-05-21" "2019-05-14" "2019-05-09" "2019-05-07" "2019-05-03" "2019-04-30" "2019-04-24" "2019-04-19" "2019-04-12" "2019-03-28"
[133] "2019-03-27" "2019-03-26" "2019-03-13" "2019-03-08" "2019-02-22" "2019-02-01" "2019-01-29" "2019-01-16" "2019-01-15" "2019-01-11" "2018-12-20"
[144] "2018-12-12" "2018-12-05" "2018-11-29" "2018-11-27"
```

```
jrn_not
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Name             twitter_handle Follower_count
   <chr>            <chr>                   <dbl>
 1 Paul Begala      @PaulBegala            235900
 2 Ana Cabrera      @AnaCabrera            211600
 3 Josh Campbell    @joshscampbell         229500
 4 Chris Cillizza   @ChrisCillizza         642500
 5 S.E. Cupp        @secupp                464100
 6 Hala Gorani      @HalaGorani            206700
 7 Dr. Sanjay Gupta @drsanjaygupta        2500000
 8 Omar Jimenez     @OmarJimenez           301400
 9 Andrew Kaczynski @KFILE                 445300
10 John King        @JohnKingCNN           590900
11 Donie O'Sullivan @donie                 286200
12 Jeff Zeleny      @jeffzeleny            308500
```

Using the following code adds all dates `tucker_df$Dato` to every row in `jrn_not`. However, is there a way to add single dates from `tucker_df$Dato` one by one so I end up with a data frame `jrn_not` consisting of 147x12 row

```
jrn_not$date <- list(as.list(tucker_df$Dato))

 jrn_not
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   Name             twitter_handle Follower_count date        
   <chr>            <chr>                   <dbl> <list>      
 1 Paul Begala      @PaulBegala            235900 <list [147]>
 2 Ana Cabrera      @AnaCabrera            211600 <list [147]>
 3 Josh Campbell    @joshscampbell         229500 <list [147]>
 4 Chris Cillizza   @ChrisCillizza         642500 <list [147]>
 5 S.E. Cupp        @secupp                464100 <list [147]>
 6 Hala Gorani      @HalaGorani            206700 <list [147]>
 7 Dr. Sanjay Gupta @drsanjaygupta        2500000 <list [147]>
 8 Omar Jimenez     @OmarJimenez           301400 <list [147]>
 9 Andrew Kaczynski @KFILE                 445300 <list [147]>
10 John King        @JohnKingCNN           590900 <list [147]>
11 Donie O'Sullivan @donie                 286200 <list [147]>
12 Jeff Zeleny      @jeffzeleny            308500 <list [147]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data frame is

```
df <- iris[seq(10),]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
#7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
#8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
#9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
```

And you want to add

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

Then you can replicate the values and `cbind`, i.e.

```
cbind(df, new = rep(x, each = nrow(df)))

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   1
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   1
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   1
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   1
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa   1
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa   1
11          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
12          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
13          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   2
14          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   2
15          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
16          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   2
17          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   2
18          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa   2
19          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
20          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa   2
21          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   3
22          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   3
23          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   3
24          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   3
25          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   3
26          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   3
27          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa   3
28          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa   3
29          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa   3
30          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa   3
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion  @Sotos. In your case the final output should be a data frame consisting of 30 rows where rows 1-10 have `1`,  rows11-20 have `2`, and rows 21-30 have `3` in the last column

Comment: Oh i did it the other way around hahaha let me revise

Comment: Corrected. Have a look

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Thank you @Sotos.